# How to get vee-validator's $validator when using nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have installed `vee-validator` in my `nuxt.js` install (using the [express template](https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template)).

I have added the plugin into my `nuxt.config.js` file like so:

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~plugins/vee-validate.js' }
]
```

I have also added it into the build settings:

```
build: {
    vendor: ['vee-validate'],
    ...
```

When I use the HTML tags e.g. `v-validate="'required'"`, the validation is working as expected, and I can show/hide errors in the template.

Now I am trying to set up a form so that when it is submitted, all fields will be validated and errors will only be displayed after an attempted submission. To do this, I have set up a method like so:

```
  methods: {
    onLogin: (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('validator', this.$validator)
    }
  }
```

For some reason, the `this.$validator` is undefined. Can someone tell me how I can access it please? I have tried adding:

```
inject: ['$validator']
```

but this didn't seem to make any difference.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was using the ES6 function style, got in the habit of using it from Angular!

Changed:

```
methods: {
    onLogin: (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('validator', this.$validator)
    }
}
```

to:

```
methods: {
    onLogin: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('validator', this.$validator)
    }
}
```

and now it works fine.

Comment: The preferred syntax is actually to use the method shorthand:

`onLogin(e) {}`